# Heimdal kerberos ipropd-master failing on start-up with "open (null): Bad address" error

Tags: replication, kerberos, heimdal

I am trying to set up a Heimdal KDC environment with one master and one replica. When I try to start the replication service on the master, it fails with this error:

```
ipropd-master[22640]: open (null): Bad address
```

The command I am running is this:

```
/usr/sbin/ipropd-master -c /etc/heimdal-kdc/kdc.conf -k /etc/heimdal-kdc/iprop.keytab
```

Here is part of an strace I ran on the command:

```
open("/etc/heimdal-kdc/kdc.conf", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "# Heimdal KDC configuration.  -*"..., 4096) = 4096
...
open("/var/run/ipropd-master.pid", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
write(3, "23677", 5)                    = 5
close(3)                                = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/dev/log"}, 110) = 0
...
open("/var/lib/heimdal-kdc/m-key", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
read(5, "\5", 1)                        = 1
read(5, "\2", 1)                        = 1
close(5)                                = 0
close(4)                                = 0
open(NULL, O_RDONLY)                    = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
open("/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY)        = 5
```

It appears that `ipropd-master` is trying to open something but the argument to the open system call is `NULL`. This is happening right after `ipropd-master` has read the file `/var/lib/heimdal-kdc/m-key`.

I cannot figure out what `ipropd-master` is trying to open and failing to do so. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: An inspection of `./lib/kadm5/ipropd_master.c` indicates that `log_file` probably isn't set, assuming `"open %s"` matches up with your `open (null)` error.

Comment: The kdc is logging to `/var/log/auth`. The only line from ipropd_master I see in that file is `open (null): Bad address`. So, where do I set the log destination for ipropd_master?

Answer (score 0):

My problem turned out to be mismatched packages: I had a locally-built version of the `heimdal-kdc` package but more-recent stock packages for the other heimdal components.